# Horizonless Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, css, maps, html5-canvas

Would it be possible to project (transform) Google Maps to achieve something similar to this image ? A horizonless projection into a concave curved plane.

Or, even better, to achieve the same with Here Maps [3D view](http://here.com/49.653049,0.3033837,5,0,0,3d.day) (canvas) .

[image]

Comment: You could take the image from a google map and project it using WebGL onto a curved plane, but it would lack the change in perspective of the buildings. It'll still look like a flat image projected onto a curve.

Comment: But then wouldn't be a functional interface. I was thinking more along the lines of applying CSS3 transforms to the tiles.